# __str__() help python 3

Tags: python-3.x, loops, oop, blackjack

I append all possible cards in `self.deck` list but when I tried to print out the list with string representation method it gave me `<__main__.Deck object at 0x00238148>` I don't know why! My code is below and I would really appreciate if anyone could look at it and just tell me how to get all `card` in class `Deck`?

```
suits = ('Hearts', 'Diamonds', 'Spades', 'Clubs')
ranks = ('Two', 'Three', 'Four', 'Five', 'Six', 'Seven', 'Eight', 'Nine', 'Ten', 'Jack', 'Queen', 'King', 'Ace')

class Card():

    def __init__(self, suit, rank):
        self.suit = suit
        self.rank = rank

    def __str__(self):
        return self.rank + " of " + self.suit


class Deck():

    def __init__(self):
        self.deck = []
        for suit in suits:
            for rank in ranks:
                self.deck.append(Card(suit, rank))

    def __str__(self):
        for card in self.deck:
            return card

deck = Deck()
print(deck)
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The `__str__` method should always return string. Here in your card class the return type of `__str__` is correct but in the Deck class you are returning the card object rather you should call the string representation of the card object inside `__str__` method.

```
   class Deck():

    def __init__(self):
        self.deck = []
        for suit in suits:
            for rank in ranks:
                self.deck.append(Card(suit, rank))

    def __str__(self):
        for card in self.deck:
            return str(card)
```

Answer (score 0):

`return` returns the value after it from the function, ending the function. You only return once from a function. Your `__str__` function should return one string, and it should contain everything you want in that string. You could loop over your deck and add to a string:

```
s = ''
for card in self.deck:
    s += str(card) + ', '
```

But then you'd have to deal with the extra comma on the end. But there's no need to reinvent the wheel. Lists in Python can be turned into strings with `str()`, so

```
str(self.deck)
```

will be something like

```
'[Two of Hearts, Three of Hearts, ... ]'
```

If you want more flexibility, you can use the `join` method of strings, which can take a list:

```
'; '.join(self.deck)
```

would be something like

```
'Two of Hearts; Three of Hearts; ...'
```

Comment: I got a question. Are "str(card)" & "card.__str__()" same things or different from each other?

Comment: @RahulTirkey basically the same. `str(x)` returns `x.__str__()` if it's defined, or if it's not defined, it returns `repr(x)`, which returns `x.__repr__()`.